# JavaScript TextNode update

Tags: javascript, dom, innerhtml, createtextnode

If I have a

```
var t = document.createTextNode(text)
parent.appendChild(t);
```

Is it possible to simply update the contents of `t`?

I would like to change the text inside the `parent` without using `removeChild`, `createTextNode` and `appendChild`. Why would I need this instead of just using `innerHTML`? Because I don't want to update the contents of the element with HTML code and the `text` may contain special characters, such as < or & which should be parsed by `TextNode`'s DOM methods.

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: Do you want to display actual HTML or really just plain text?

Comment: I want to change the text inside parent and make it appear as plain text (ie, have the DOM replace < with &lt;).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Be aware that adjacent text nodes are collapsed into one (since there is really no way to distinguish two adjacent text nodes).

The contents of a text node can be updated using it's `nodeValue` property (see [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.nodeValue)).

Since a text node by it's very definition cannot contain any markup, there is no `innerHTML` property.

Comment: Perfect :) Just what i'm looking for

Answer (score 2):

If you keep the instance of the TextNode object (t in your example code) then you can change the content using various functions like replaceData(), substringData(), etc..

See this page for a nice reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535905(VS.85).aspx#

Answer (score 2):

```
parent.innerText = text;
```

Comment: That's an alternative, of cause. I thought you were asking about text nodes specifically.

Comment: "I would like to change the text inside the parent" probably wasn't specific enough to say that I don't care how, I just want something very simple that will use the DOM to escape HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Below example code overwrites the "Old Value" of the text node with the "New Value".

```
const textNode = document.createTextNode("Old Value");
parent.appendChild(textNode);

textNode.nodeValue = "New Value";
```